# Center a table horizontally with iText's XMLWorker

Tags: itext, xmlworker

I've tried centering a table in two ways:

Attempt 1 code:

```
<h1>Attempt 1</h1>

<table style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr>
        <th>foo</th>
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>foo</th>
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Attempt 2 code:

```
<h1>Attempt 2</h1>

<table style="width: 50%;" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>foo</th>
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>foo</th>
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Using the XMLWorker demo: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/

This is the HTML preview:

[image: html preview]

As you can see, both tables are centered.
Although, when I click "transform", I get this:

[image: generated pdf]

I also tried later wrapping the table in a `<div style="text-align: center"></div>` which didn't work

Comment: Much to my surprise, setting the alignment of a table isn't supported (yet) in XML Worker. However, it's fairly easy to add support for the `align` attribute. It only took me a handful of lines of code to implement this. It's now in our private gitlab repository. The changes will be pushed to github soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comment section, this isn't supported yet in XML Worker. We'll add it to the next release. If you can't wait until the next release, please apply this patch:

```
diff --git a/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/html/table/Table.java b/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/html/table/Table.java
index 541818bfc9..e262b4a406 100644
--- a/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/html/table/Table.java
+++ b/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/html/table/Table.java
@@ -165,6 +165,19 @@ public class Table extends AbstractTagProcessor {
             table.setHeaderRows(headerRows + footerRows);
             table.setFooterRows(footerRows);

+            if ( tag.getAttributes().containsKey(HTML.Attribute.ALIGN)) {
+                String value = tag.getAttributes().get(HTML.Attribute.ALIGN);
+                if ( value != null ) {
+                    if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(CSS.Value.RIGHT)) {
+                        table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
+                    } else if ( value.equalsIgnoreCase(CSS.Value.LEFT)) {
+                        table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
+                    } else if ( value.equalsIgnoreCase(CSS.Value.CENTER)) {
+                        table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
+                    }
+                }
+            }
+
             int direction = getRunDirection(tag);
             if (direction != PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_DEFAULT) {
                 table.setRunDirection(direction);
```

Comment: So in the next release, the way to align it will be like in my `attempt 2` code?

Comment: Yes, but the next release is still a couple of months away (we've only just released 5.5.6), and that's why I'm sending you the patch. This way you can create your own intermediate release.